# Easy way to translate attributes of models in a web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, web, rubygems

I have a web appplication where I sort photographies into categories. These categories are currently in Swedish but i want to add the option to add an english translation of the category names.

If the categories had been static I could've just added translations to the locale files, but now that a user should be able to add categories (and translations), I'm not sure how to go about it.

How would I go about doing this? The obvious first thought is to add columns for each language into the database table like `title_en`, `title_sv` etc but I guess that'll quickly become impractical as later on in the project, the customer will probably like to add more languages.

Anyone done something similar before? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails i18n system allows different backends. If you Google "rails i18n backend," you'll find several implementations and examples.

You could use a database for this. Here's a RailsCast demonstrating [managing the translations through a web interface](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends).

Comment: This seems like the most reasonable solution I guess. I'm not sure how to easily handle the translations in the model but I guess I'll just have to think a bit about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible solutions. My first choice whould be to add a a `lang:string` field and `parent_id:integer` to the categories table. Then you add a self referential association to the `Category` (I assume its called Categrory,...) model.

```
belongs_to :translated, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
has_many :translations, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

Then add a scope to your model that filters by the `lang` field.

```
scope :language, lambda{|lang| where("lang = ?", lang)}
```

And a `translate` method.

```
def translate(lang)
  self.translations.language(lang).first if self.translations.language(lang).any?
end
```

So you can have one main language and add any amount of other languages.

Another possibilty whould be to add a `translations:text` field to your model and `serialize` it. So you can store the translations in a hash that is serializes. The downside of that solution whould be that serialized fields cant be searched that easy.